# Will ROS be able to run on the Raspberry Pi?

Tags: robotic-arm, raspberrypi

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Will ROS be able to run on the [Raspberry Pi](http://www.raspberrypi.org)?
It uses an ARM1176JZF-S core.
The provisional hardware specification is [here](http://elinux.org/RaspberryPiBoard#Provisional_specification).
Debian, Fedora and Archlinux will be supported at launch.
Cost is expected to be very low.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/11406/will-ros-be-able-to-run-on-the-raspberry-pi?/) by [jonititan](https://answers.ros.org/users/1159/jonititan/) on ROS Answers with karma: 51 on 2011-10-04

Post score: 5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Given the specs and that it can run some forms of Linux, I would expect that some level of ROS software can run on the Raspberry Pi. I expect you would be able to run most of the core ROS packages (such as the communications or even some more math heavy packages such as tf at slower rates) pretty well.

If you try to run complex software such as navigation, the single core will probably start to have trouble keeping up with everything (not to mention any slowdowns due to things like Eigen probably not being very well optimized for ARM11 compared to x86 or x86-64). It may be possible to run something like navigation with appropriate configuration tweaking for the slower CPU.

All that said, for the cost of an Arduino, you are definitely getting a lot more computing power so it definitely has possibilities.

---

Originally posted by [Eric Perko](https://answers.ros.org/users/14/eric-perko/) with karma: 8406 on 2011-10-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The core of ROS does run on ARM based processors.  [armel deb build status -- ROS Electric](http://www.ros.org/debbuild/electric.html)

I know that people run ROS on Gumstix, PandaBoards and BeagleBoards.  Usually on top of Linaro or Ubuntu.  If you use Ubuntu you can use the binary debs linked above, otherwise you can use the compile from source installation method.

[binary install instructions](http://www.ros.org/wiki/electric/Installation/Ubuntu)

[source install instructions](http://www.ros.org/wiki/electric/Installation/Ubuntu/Source)

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2011-10-04

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Yes - I'm running it now.

All the basics seem to be working and TurtleSim's not too bad.

Not tried the navigation stuff yet - might be able to have a bunch of Pi's running together each with a bit each :)

M

---

Originally posted by [MarkyMark2012](https://answers.ros.org/users/2193/markymark2012/) with karma: 1834 on 2012-05-20

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Kevin](https://answers.ros.org/users/186/kevin/) on 2012-05-20**:
Can you document somewhere what you needed to do to get it running? Maybe just make a "question" here on answers.ros.org on "how to install ROS on PI" or something like that and then answer it.

**Comment by [MarkyMark2012](https://answers.ros.org/users/2193/markymark2012/) on 2012-05-20**:
Hi Kevin - will do. Later today or tomorrow. Cheers Mark

**Comment by [MarkyMark2012](https://answers.ros.org/users/2193/markymark2012/) on 2012-05-21**:
http://answers.ros.org/question/34501/how-to-setting-up-ros-on-raspberrypi/?answer=34502#post-id-34502